# Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xB9\x82\xE0\xB8\xA3...' for column 'text' at row 1

Tags: mysql, django

In my Django app I am reading a text file and uploading it as a LongText field in the mysql database. My database supports UTF-8 encoding but I get the following error:

> Exception Type: Warning at /upload Exception Value: Incorrect string
>   value: '\xE0\xB9\x82\xE0\xB8\xA3...' for column 'text' at row 1

The code which converts it to the unicode in python is here:

```
fileobj = self.request.FILES.get('filepath', None)
filetext = unicode(fileobj.read(), 'utf-8') 
uploadedText = models.UploadedText()
uploadedText.text = filetext uploadedText.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have set your database collation to utf8_general_ci and that your UploadedText model looks something like this:

```
class UploadedText(models.Model):
  text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Then try out this code:

```
fileobj = self.request.FILES.get('filepath', None)
filetext = fileobj.read() 
uploadedText = models.UploadedText()
uploadedText.text = filetext 
uploadedText.save()
```

**You don't need to explicitly convert the contents of the file to unicode** if they are already in unicode. Also test this code for a file with only ascii contents to see if you get the required response.

Hope this helps. If you encounter any further errors please POST them.
Cheers